# Writing a geopackage error - violating constraints?

Tags: gis, ogr2ogr, geopackage

I have a geopackage that I want to split into many smaller geopackages. Kind of like 'tiles'. I have been successfully using the ogr2ogr tool for many countries around the world. But for some reason this bit does not work (the area in question is Russia, though I'm not sure that has anything to do with it). I don't understand the error the sqlite3_exec is giving me. Can anyone advise please?

```
ogr2ogr -spat 33 39 33.25 39.25 -clipsrc spat_extent -f GPKG "tile_69.gpkg" "basins.gpkg" -nlt GEOMETRYCOLLECTION

ERROR 1: sqlite3_exec(CREATE TABLE gpkg_spatial_ref_sys (srs_name TEXT NOT NULL,srs_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,organization TEXT NOT NULL,organization_coordsys_id INTEGER NOT NULL,definition  TEXT NOT NULL,description TEXT);INSERT INTO gpkg_spatial_ref_sys (srs_name, srs_id, organization, organization_coordsys_id, definition, description) VALUES ('WGS 84 geodetic', 4326, 'EPSG', 4326, 'GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Longitude",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]', 'longitude/latitude coordinates in decimal degrees on the WGS 84 spheroid');
INSERT INTO gpkg_spatial_ref_sys (srs_name, srs_id, organization, organization_coordsys_id, definition, description) VALUES ('Undefined Cartesian SRS', -1, 'NONE', -1, 'undefined', 'undefined Cartesian coordinate reference system');INSERT INTO gpkg_spatial_ref_sys (srs_name, srs_id, organization, organization_coordsys_id, definition, description) VALUES ('Undefined geographic SRS', 0, 'NONE', 0, 'undefined', 'undefined geographic coordinate reference system');CREATE TABLE gpkg_contents (table_name TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,data_type TEXT NOT NULL,identifier TEXT UNIQUE,description TEXT DEFAULT '',last_change DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%fZ','now')),min_x DOUBLE, min_y DOUBLE,max_x DOUBLE, max_y DOUBLE,srs_id INTEGER,CONSTRAINT fk_gc_r_srs_id FOREIGN KEY (srs_id) REFERENCES gpkg_spatial_ref_sys(srs_id));CREATE TABLE gpkg_ogr_contents(table_name TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,feature_count INTEGER DEFAULT NULL);CREATE TABLE gpkg_geometry_columns (table_name TEXT NOT NULL,column_name TEXT NOT NULL,geometry_type_name TEXT NOT NULL,srs_id INTEGER NOT NULL,z TINYINT NOT NULL,m TINYINT NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT pk_geom_cols PRIMARY KEY (table_name, column_name),CONSTRAINT uk_gc_table_name UNIQUE (table_name),CONSTRAINT fk_gc_tn FOREIGN KEY (table_name) REFERENCES gpkg_contents(table_name),CONSTRAINT fk_gc_srs FOREIGN KEY (srs_id) REFERENCES gpkg_spatial_ref_sys (srs_id));CREATE TABLE gpkg_tile_matrix_set (table_name TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,srs_id INTEGER NOT NULL,min_x DOUBLE NOT NULL,min_y DOUBLE NOT NULL,max_x DOUBLE NOT NULL,max_y DOUBLE NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT fk_gtms_table_name FOREIGN KEY (table_name) REFERENCES gpkg_contents(table_name),CONSTRAINT fk_gtms_srs FOREIGN KEY (srs_id) REFERENCES gpkg_spatial_ref_sys (srs_id));CREATE TABLE gpkg_tile_matrix (table_name TEXT NOT NULL,zoom_level INTEGER NOT NULL,matrix_width INTEGER NOT NULL,matrix_height INTEGER NOT NULL,tile_width INTEGER NOT NULL,tile_height INTEGER NOT NULL,pixel_x_size DOUBLE NOT NULL,pixel_y_size DOUBLE NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT pk_ttm PRIMARY KEY (table_name, zoom_level),CONSTRAINT fk_tmm_table_name FOREIGN KEY (table_name) REFERENCES gpkg_contents(table_name));CREATE TRIGGER 'gpkg_tile_matrix_zoom_level_insert' BEFORE INSERT ON 'gpkg_tile_matrix' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'insert on table ''gpkg_tile_matrix'' violates constraint: zoom_level cannot be less than 0') WHERE (NEW.zoom_level < 0); END; CREATE TRIGGER 'gpkg_tile_matrix_zoom_level_update' BEFORE UPDATE of zoom_level ON 'gpkg_tile_matrix' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'update on table ''gpkg_tile_matrix'' violates constraint: zoom_level cannot be less than 0') WHERE (NEW.zoom_level < 0); END; CREATE TRIGGER 'gpkg_tile_matrix_matrix_width_insert' BEFORE INSERT ON 'gpkg_tile_matrix' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'insert on table ''gpkg_tile_matrix'' violates constraint: matrix_width cannot be less than 1') WHERE (NEW.matrix_width < 1); END; CREATE TRIGGER 'gpkg_tile_matrix_matrix_width_update' BEFORE UPDATE OF matrix_width ON 'gpkg_tile_matrix' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'update on table ''gpkg_tile_matrix'' violates constraint: matrix_width cannot be less than 1') WHERE (NEW.matrix_width < 1); END; CREATE TRIGGER 'gpkg_tile_matrix_matrix_height_insert' BEFORE INSERT ON 'gpkg_tile_matrix' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'insert on table ''gpkg_tile_matrix'' violates constraint: matrix_height cannot be less than 1') WHERE (NEW.matrix_height < 1); END; CREATE TRIGGER 'gpkg_tile_matrix_matrix_height_update' BEFORE UPDATE OF matrix_height ON 'gpkg_tile_matrix' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'update on table ''gpkg_tile_matrix'' violates constraint: matrix_height cannot be less than 1') WHERE (NEW.matrix_height < 1); END; CREATE TRIGGER 'gpkg_tile_matrix_pixel_x_size_insert' BEFORE INSERT ON 'gpkg_tile_matrix' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'insert on table ''gpkg_tile_matrix'' violates constraint: pixel_x_size must be greater than 0') WHERE NOT (NEW.pixel_x_size > 0); END; CREATE TRIGGER 'gpkg_tile_matrix_pixel_x_size_update' BEFORE UPDATE OF pixel_x_size ON 'gpkg_tile_matrix' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'update on table ''gpkg_tile_matrix'' violates constraint: pixel_x_size must be greater than 0') WHERE NOT (NEW.pixel_x_size > 0); END; CREATE TRIGGER 'gpkg_tile_matrix_pixel_y_size_insert' BEFORE INSERT ON 'gpkg_tile_matrix' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'insert on table ''gpkg_tile_matrix'' violates constraint: pixel_y_size must be greater than 0') WHERE NOT (NEW.pixel_y_size > 0); END; CREATE TRIGGER 'gpkg_tile_matrix_pixel_y_size_update' BEFORE UPDATE OF pixel_y_size ON 'gpkg_tile_matrix' FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'update on table ''gpkg_tile_matrix'' violates constraint: pixel_y_size must be greater than 0') WHERE NOT (NEW.pixel_y_size > 0); END;) failed: unable to open database file
    ERROR 1: GPKG driver failed to create /local_disk0/ru_run_2023-06-02-09-40-30_30m/climate_change/ru_hydro_and_lisflood_tile_69.gpkg
```

Comment: Hmm. I just tried to write it to a different location and it worked. Strange.

Comment: As your issue seems solved, it would be convenient that you add your comment as an answer and mark it as answered so this is clear to everyone.

Comment: BTW: the only error is at the very end of the line: `failed: unable to open database file`. Maybe the directory you are writing in didn't exist, or the file existed already or ...